# Unable to access event.dataTransfer object of a drop event inside an asynchronous method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a simple drop zone the is used to upload files to the server. There is a `<div>` tag which accept an file to be dropped and `<h>` which shows an useful message. When an file is dropped, program upload it to the server. Once the uploading successful, it updates the header status to "Uploading  successful".

```
dropzone.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(event.dataTransfer.files[0].type !== 'image/jpeg') {
        setHeader('Dropped file is not an image');
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            setHeader('Uploading '+event.dataTransfer.files[0].name+' successful');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

But accessing dataTransfer.files[0].name returns this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. I have the idea of `Asynchronous functions`. But in this situation `Asynchronous` can not access `event.dataTransfer` object. I also tried below code which brings the same error.

```
dropzone.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
    var DragEvent = event;
    var testMessage = 'hello world';

    /* 
      some code 
    */
    else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(testMessage);
            console.log(DragEvent.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
            //setHeader('Uploading '+event.dataTransfer.files[0].name+' successful');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: sorry. I edited the  question.

Comment: You can't access `event.dataTransfer.files[0]` without checking that `event.dataTransfer.files[0]` even exists. Your code misses that check. Also, "Wait one second" and "transfer successful" are not the same thing. Don't write your code this way. A file transfer will have a "success" callback function. When this callback function is called, *then* your transfer is complete, not after some arbitrary timeout.

Comment: The reason why Javascript doesn't throw an error in this line `if(event.dataTransfer.files[0].type !== 'image/jpeg')`  because there is an file object. It's not the same but  both of them are `Asynchronous` methods which can be executed any time. The issue is, i can  access anonymous method's variables of the event listener except the event object.